# Problems 3D transforming div to flip around with text ribbon on it

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have created product box that shows product image, when hovered on flips around to show details of a product and this works well. Problem is when this product has ribbon on it and flips, text in the ribbon becomes flipped as well (it's position is correct), I need to somehow extra transform this text so it shows correctly TOP even when flipped. Is it possible?

```css
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
    width: 85px;
    height: 88px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.ribbon-green {
    font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 0;
    left: -5px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #BFDC7A;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    color: #6a6340;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 3px solid #6e8900;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
    left: 0;
}

.ribbon-green:after {
    right: 0;
}

.product-box {
    width: 292px;
    height: 340px;
}

.thumb-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
}

.product-box img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.product-box .thumb-detail {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;   
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.product-box.flip {
    perspective: 800px;
}

.product-box.flip .thumb-wrapper {
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.product-box.flip .thumb-detail, .product-box.flip:hover .thumb-wrapper {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="product-box flip">
    <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">TOP</div></div>
        <img src="#" alt="" title="" height="262" width="262">
        <div class="thumb-detail">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just duplicate the `ribbon-wrapper-green` and rotate it in the back

```css
.card {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 700;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.card:hover .front{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);  
}
.card:hover .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);  
}
.card:hover .face {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}
.front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
    background: #9dcc78;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}



.ribbon-wrapper-green {
    width: 85px;
    height: 88px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.ribbon-green {
    font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 0;
    left: -5px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #BFDC7A;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    color: #6a6340;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 3px solid #6e8900;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
    left: 0;
}

.ribbon-green:after {
    right: 0;
}

.back .ribbon-wrapper-green {
    top: -4px;
    left: -1px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
    <div class='front face'>
        <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">TOP</div></div>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/180x180'/>
    </div>
    <div class="back face">
        <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">TOP</div></div>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/180x180'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks to be the best approach without any undesired effects. It would be nice to have it non-vendor specific as it currently works only in webkit based browsers. At least non-vendor properties should be added.

Comment: @Xeevis why don't you use prefixfree by leaverou?

Comment: I can fix it for myself no problem, but answer may be useful to wider audience if standard properties were used (afaik even prefixfree needs standard property and just adds prefix as necessary). Transform, transition, perspective all that is already properly implemented in all stable releases of all note-worthy browsers, so I see no point why have -webkit- there, it's redundantly limiting and targets less users than standard :).

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** I had initially misunderstood the question and posted a wrong answer. Did not want to delete it and hence have modified the original answer to still solve the problem albeit making it more complex in the process. The best approach is provided in Tambo's answer. You can use this method if you for some reason wish to achieve the effect without duplicating elements.

You can do it by adding the `rotateY(-180deg)` on the `div` with `class="ribbon-wrapper-green"` and positioning it on the other side. The original positioning is `right: -3px` and on hover, we change it to `left: -3px` or `right: 210px;` (box width 292px + offset 3px - width of ribbon container 85px).

After this, the whole ribbon is translated by the required pixels (the complex part) to get positioned on the left side of the screen. Now, even though the position is correct, the ribbon has to be rotated in the reverse direction to make it look properly like a ribbon and so a `rotate(-90deg)` is added (-90 degrees the element is originally rotated by 45 degree which has to be nullified to come back to a normal position and then we have to rotate another 45 degree in the reverse direction).

Note: The animation/transition effect is not great but I think you can work that out.

```css
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.ribbon-green:before,
.ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 3px solid #6e8900;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}
.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}
.product-box {
  width: 292px;
  height: 340px;
}
.thumb-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
.product-box img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.product-box .thumb-detail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.product-box.flip {
  perspective: 800px;
}
.product-box.flip .thumb-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.product-box.flip .thumb-detail,
.product-box.flip:hover .thumb-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.product-box.flip:hover .thumb-wrapper .ribbon-wrapper-green {
  left: -3px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg) translate(-212px) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg) translate(-212px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="product-box flip">
  <div class="thumb-wrapper">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green">
      <div class="ribbon-green">TOP</div>
    </div>
    <img src="#" alt="" title="" height="262" width="262">
    <div class="thumb-detail">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Default ribbon has to be on right, when flipped it has to be on the left side as it looks better when it's not jumping around, I want it to look realistic. So ribbon is essentially working well, just its text needs to behave differently.

Comment: @Xeevis: Please check my updated answer. It is a bit complex but you can use this method if you wish to avoid duplication of elements.